# Why can't get POSTFIELDS after add header?

Tags: php, php-curl

This is code in client:

```
//Create XML Object
$newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
$newsXML->addAttribute('newsPagePrefix', 'value goes here');
$newsIntro = $newsXML->addChild('content',"test data");
$newsIntro->addAttribute('type', 'latest');

// URL of api
$url = 'http://localhost:81/demophp/api2.php';

// init CURL
$ch = curl_init($url);
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/xml',
    'Authorization: 123456',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// exist return value
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
// method:  POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
// parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["xml"=>$newsXML->asXML()]);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This is code of `api2.php`

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    if($header=="Authorization")
    echo "$header: $value";
}

$xmlstr=$_POST["xml"];
$myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $xmlstr);
fclose($myfile);

$xml= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $newsXML['newsPagePrefix'];
exit;
```

If i remove `header`, it can get `xml`.
but If i add header to `curl`

```
$headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/xml',
        'Authorization: 123456',
    );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

It occur error can't get `xml`:

```
Authorization: 123456
Notice: Undefined index: xml in D:\demophp\api2.php on line 8

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in
```

Why can't get POSTFIELDS after add header?

Comment: Because you set content type to application/xml And then you insert postfields instead of the xml body

Comment: How fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Well dont set the content type. Or make the xml the raw body of the request.

Comment: If [Or make the xml the raw body of the request] , in api2.php, how can get xml string?

Comment: If you put the xml directly into body you Will probably have to file_get_contents('php://input');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this curl script . it may work for you.

```
   $newsXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<news></news>");
    $newsXML->addAttribute('newsPagePrefix', 'value goes here');
    $newsIntro = $newsXML->addChild('content',"test data");
    $newsIntro->addAttribute('type', 'latest');
    // URL of api
    $url = 'http://localhost:81/demophp/api2.php';
    $input_xml = $newsXML->asXML();
    // init CURL
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $headers = array(
         'Content-type: application/xml',
        'Authorization: 123456'

    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    // exist return value
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // method:  POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input_xml); 
    // parameters
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This is code of api2.php

```
 $headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    if($header=="Authorization")
    echo "$header: $value";
}

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$xmlstr=$data;
$myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $xmlstr);
fclose($myfile);
$xml= new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $xml['newsPagePrefix'];
exit;
```